# "Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" while sending mail from nodejs using office 365 mail

Tags: node.js, office365, nodemailer

I am getting error "Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" while trying to send mail using nodejs.

Below is my configuration

```
this._transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Outlook365',
            name: 'smtp.office365.com',
            host: 'smtp.office365.com', // Office 365 server
            port: '587',     
            secure: false,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
                pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
            },
            secureConnection: false,
            tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }
        })
```

and while sending the mail

```
var mailOptions = {
                from: `Admin<${settingObj.Contact_Email}>`,
                to: req.body.email,
                subject: "Subject",
                html: 'Hello ' + '<b>' + req.body.email + '<br>Thank You for contacting'
            };
            var sendMail = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

below is sendmail function

```
async sendMail(from, to, subject, tplName, locals) {
        try {
            const mailer = new Mailer();
            const templateDir = path.join(__dirname, "../views/", 'email-templates', tplName + '/html')
            const email = new Email({
                message: { from: from },
                transport: { jsonTransport: true },
                views: { root: templateDir, options: { extension: 'ejs' } }
            });
            let getResponse = await email.render(templateDir, locals);
            if (getResponse) {
                let options = { from: from, to: to, subject: subject, html: getResponse };
                let mailresponse = await mailer._transport.sendMail(options);
                if (mailresponse) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("44>>", e.message);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: do you have 2 factor authentication enabled?

Comment: @deechris27 no. 2 factor authentication is not enabled.

Comment: Share your code..I'll try with my office 365 creds, if it works then we could be sure it's not a code issue and focus on o365 settings related to this or your firewall-related stuff.

Comment: @deechris27 updated the code in question

Comment: Updated my answer. Use my code as-is, comment out the async sendMail(from, to, subject, tplName, locals) function. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: what's the status?

Comment: Getting this error now: `Message failed: 554 5.2.252 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. [Hostname=VI1PR10MB2237.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"`

Comment: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME and `Admin<${settingObj.Contact_Email}>` are same?

Comment: Its working after setting both `auth.user` and `from` email same. But I did not received mail.

Comment: check your spam or junk folder, if it's working then there is no code issue.

Comment: @deechris27 its nowhere

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything, ensure you are able to log in to your office 365 account with your username and password.

if you're facing this error in a hosted app, make sure you've created the env variables in config-vars/parameter-store/secrets or whichever is applicable for the platform?

Use [telnet to access your office 365 SMTP account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/test-smtp-with-telnet?view=exchserver-2019), doing so, you can get to know if it's a problem with your code or the settings.

Here is my working code,

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, resp)=>{

    const email = `
       <h3>Hello dee.....</h3>
       <ul>
         <li>Name: Deepak </li>
         <li>Email: dee@dee.com </li>
       </ul>
       <h2>Message<h2>
       <p>Wassup....howdeeee</p>
    `

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.office365.com",
        port: '587',
        auth: {
          user: '....',
          pass: 'blahhhhh'
        },
        secureConnection: false,
        tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }    
      });
    
      transporter.sendMail({
        from: '.....',
        to: '.....',
        subject: 'Test for twix',
        text: 'hello twix',
        html: email
      }).then(res=>{

          console.log("success........", res)
          resp.send("yeahhhhhhhh", res);
      }).catch(e=>{
          console.log("failed........", e)
      });
});


app.listen(5000, console.log("Server listening to 6k"));
```

I enabled two-factor authentication and logged out of all active sessions then tried again, it worked fine with the above code.

**Updated answer in response to comments**

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();

app.get('/send', async (req, resp) => {

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.office365.com",
    port: '587',
    auth: {
      user: '......',
      pass: '......'
    },
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: '.......',
    to:   '.......',
    subject: "Twix mailer",
    html: 'Hello ' + '<b>' + 'deechris27' + '<br>Thank You for contacting'
  };

  let sendMail = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  console.log("twix email.....", sendMail.response);
});
app.listen(5000, console.log("Server listening to 5k"));
```

**Success message below**

[image]

**Suggested changes**

```
this._transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Outlook365',       // remove this
            name: 'smtp.office365.com',  // not needed
            host: 'smtp.office365.com', 
            port: '587',     
            secure: false,               // remove this
            auth: {
                user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,  // hardcode username to try
                pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,  // hardcode pwd to try in local
            },
            secureConnection: false,
            tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }
        });
```

**comment out** sendMail(from, to, subject, tplName, locals) function. Where is this called? this appears to be like you're trying to do what Nodemailer does internally. Though it wouldn't throw an invalid login error, I advise you to comment out for debugging.

I got the email "Hello **deechris27** Thank You for contacting" to my inbox when this
`let sendMail = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);` promise was resolved.

createTransport of nodemailer returns an **instance of Mailer** which provides the sendMail function. The "**From**" address in mailOptions should be **same** as the **auth.user**.

I'm using [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) Version 6.6.3. Refer to node_modules -> nodemailer -> lib -> nodemailer.js for more clarity.

**Helpful Resources**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/i-cant-send-e-mails-from-my-server-through-office/999b353e-9d4f-49b2-9da9-14d6d4e6dfb5

Answer (score 0):

On your Outlook dashboard, you need to allow less secure apps from your outlook account to send emails. Through this link. [Allow less secure apps](https://superuser.com/questions/1521236/how-to-allow-less-secure-app-access-in-microsoft-email)

Comment: Try adding `tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }` when creating the transport

Comment: Try updating your host to the one microsoft gives the company when an office365 account is created as cited here: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/949#issuecomment-434908474